# Haskell - Can't find file test.hs

Tags: haskell

I just started with haskell. Now im trying to set things up at home. So I write my code in **sublimetext 3** and try and load it from **cmd**. Then I get the message,

```
<no location info>: can't find file: test.hs
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

My file is named test.hs and this is all the code it contains:

```
double :: Int -> Int

double x = x + xb
```

Thanks in advance 
/Michael

Comment: you are likely not in the correct directory. check with `dir` whether the file is really there...

Comment: @sdx23 Really saved me some ear-scratching.